# Creating a self-made replica of the erase() function in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, runtime-error, erase

I am trying to create a function to do what the built-in function `.erase()` does in c++ with the following code:

```
string delChar(string text, int no_of_ch_to_delete, int starting_point)
{
    int Final_Point = starting_point + no_of_ch_to_delete;
    for (int i = starting_point; i <= Final_Point; i++)
    {
        text = text.at(i) = '\0';
    }
    return text;
}
```

This is giving me an error that I am unable to figure out:

```
Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::at(...) returned 0xCD9CC6C4.
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: `text = text.at(i) = '\0';` Why are are you assigning the value returned by `at` to `text`?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
text = text.at(i) = '\0';
```

is effectively the same as

```
text.at(i) = '\0';
text = '\0';
```

The last line replaces any contents of the string `text` with the single character `\0`. `text` has now `1` element and any further access via `at(i)` is out-of-bounds.

Comment: Declaring a separate variable to store the shortened string does get rid of the error but does not give the required output, why is that?

Comment: @solopolo You need to review how `std::string` actually works. A `std::string` can contain `\0`s in the middle, you cannot "resize" a `std::string` like that